# Are there any issues with using an on ground sprinkler system with impact sprinklers?

Tags: lawn, watering, sprinkler-system

I recently bought a home, and now I am tired of watering the lawn every day. I considered under ground sprinkler system but they are very expensive. I thought to do my own diy on the on ground sprinkler system connecting each impact sprinkler with hoses, But I didn't find much luck online. I am wondering if there is any issue with having the system on the ground instead of underground? Also please let me know where can I find online design service to design my lawn. I am thinking to connect impact sprinklers with 25 foot hoses not more than 4 for a water line. I tried connecting 3 impact sprinklers and it worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

How large of an area do you need to water?  I've used oscillating sprinklers on whole nurseries and on my own landscapes with lots of success.  The cheaper the oscillating sprinkler, the better.  Weird, huh.  Do make sure how much you water (NOT every day) by putting out straight-sided cans like cat-food cans.  1" deep once per week is the *average* goal (can be done 1/4" 4 days a week or 1/2" twice per week...)  Use a shovel to make sure you water the soil down to 4-6" in depth.  Then allow to dry out! Do not allow plants to stress or wilt but training your plants to grow deep roots helps with drought-tolerance.  Are you on city water or do you have your own well?

I've installed many, many irrigation systems and they work great IF you understand how plants thrive and if you understand how to program your system.  Most irrigation companies set timers to go off everyday for a few minutes each zone.  Bad idea.  You have to set out the cans, time your irrigation zones, each and every one.

Buying a 7 dollar oscillating sprinkler is what I've been doing forever.  I'll leave it going until my beds, lawns are SOAKED.  Half an hour...an hour...depends on your soil, slopes, drainage.  You want your soil WET down to 4-6" and then you want to allow your soil to dry before you water again.  Check your sod's soil and your planting bed soil separately.

Sandy soils will need to be watered more often, clay a lot less often.  While you are at it, check the soil's pH.  Lawn's tend to be more alkaline, plant beds can be more acidic.  Don't forget to aerate your lawn areas at least once per year leaving the plugs on top of the soil.

If you decide to get an automatic watering system, the best time is AFTER all your plants are planted and the lawns have definitive edges.  You won't be able to tell where the lines are installed...if done correctly.  Get to know your timer and how to program the thing.  Don't be afraid to call the company that installed your system for advice and if you live in areas with winters, to have the same company blow out your system and recharge it every fall and spring.